# Variable product in WP woocomnerce - only some attrs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am using WP and woocommerce.

I created variable product but it use all of attributes. It is possible to create variation which will use only some attributes?

Lets say that we have attrs: color, size, gender

I would like to create variation:
color: black, size: XL - but I do not want to specify gender, because it does not matter to me

Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: Yes. When you create a variation you can set the attribute to "any. Ex: "Any Gender".

Comment: yes, but in that case there is still Gender select, but I guess that http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/2.3.7/filters/woocommerce_available_variation/ and some jquery magic will help

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that you didn't want a front-end choice. If it doesn't matter, then why use the gender attribute when creating your variations?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just remove the gender attribute from Products > Attribute.

Or when you are creating a new product, you can specify specific attributes you wanna use.

1. Add new product
2. Set product data to "variable product"
3. Go to "Attributes" tab
4. Select attribute from dropdown on top right (gathered from saved attributes)

Comment: But I do not want to remove Gender attribute, because Gender attribute does not matter only if the color is black and size XL, otherwise gender is requiered attribute